# Checking for a valid pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this vector of pointers

```
std::vector<Connection *> List;

typedef struct {
    int Initialized;
....
} Connection;
```

My program is core dumping somewhere in these 5 lines. What could be the problem?

```
1 for ( size_t i = 0; i < List.size(); i++ ) { 
2       if ( List[i]->Initialized ) {
3           counter++ ;
4       }
5} /* for() */`
```

1. `List[i]` is pointing to some garbage location. so when you access List[i]->Initialized, it core dumps. Can I check for `NULL` here to prevent the core dump? My understanding is checking for `NULL` will not work as the pointer can be pointing to garbage and still be valid.   So can I add some check before line 2 here, to prevent the core dump?
2. The `List.size()` has a huge number,so the for loop never ends??

Am I missing some other scenarios here? we don't know what is causing this issue, so can't reproduce it. For some reason I am unable to use gdb or dbx on this system.

Comment: If you cannot reproduce it, then why do you care...

Comment: You cannot check for invariants you failed to establish. Only depend on some variable being initialized after you did the deed.

Comment: gdb is your friend!!

Comment: At some point you are pushing garbage into the vector... don't do that!

Comment: Maybe use [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) i.e. `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Connection>>`

Comment: Please consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new

Comment: Try to check that code with valgrind for any invalid data. Just write a  small test case and check that with valgrind: http://valgrind.org/gallery/linux_mag.html

Answer (score 2):

> So can I add some check before line 2 here, to prevent the core dump?

No, you can't check whether a pointer is valid. The way to avoid dereferencing invalid pointers is to make sure that, at every point in your code, you already *know* which pointers are valid and which are invalid. This may involve some combination of:

1. Not inserting invalid pointers into the container in the first place
2. Ensuring that any pointers that become invalid are removed from the container before or immediately after this occurs

> The List.size() has a huge number,so the for loop never ends??

This would not cause a core dump.

Another possibility is that your code has some undefined behaviour so that `List`'s memory becomes corrupted before the loop is entered.

You can use a debugger such as gdb to examine the core file and determine which instruction caused the core dump.

Comment: for some reason I am not able to use a debugger on this system.

Answer (score 1):

One may initialize that particular underlying data structure with a constructor set `initialized` to the appropriate value.

Defining a container storing a pointer capture by a smart-pointer:

```
std::vector < std::shared_ptr < Connection > > list
```

Filling the vector is done by, e.g.,

```
list.push_back ( std::make_shared < Connection > ( /* arg1, arg2, ... */ );
```

Finally, you can simply check whether the smart-pointer of an indexn i is valid.

```
for ( ... )  {   
   if ( List[i] ) {
   }
}
```

Comment: This is still going to probably-crash if `List[i]` is an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @cdhowie You are right, but my answer was before the question was complete.